# adding apt repo with pallet

Tags: elasticsearch, apt, pallet

I'm trying to add the elasticsearch debian repo to a server-spec.  I have this function

```
(defn add-es-source []
  (package-source "elasticsearch"
  :aptitude {:url "http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/1.0/debian"
             :scopes ["stable" "main"]}))
```

which adds the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch.list`

`deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/1.0/debian raring stable main`

However the raring specific repo does not exist so I get 404s when apt repos are updated.  How can I stop this version name being added with `package-source`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply an empty string for the release key.

```
(defn add-es-source []
  (package-source "elasticsearch"
    :aptitude
    {:url "http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/1.0/debian"
     :release ""
     :key-url "http://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch"
     :scopes ["stable" "main"]}))
```

Note that I also added the key-url.